# What is the correct way of return a List in Spring

Tags: java, spring, list, data-structures

I have written a method which annotated with a Spring.it will return a List. following code snip will represent that method.

```
   @RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvailableRooms(
            @RequestParam(name = "checkin")
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
            LocalDate checkin,
            @RequestParam(name = "checkout")
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
            LocalDate checkout) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

What i want to know is if i write it as this will it be a wrong?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvailableRooms(
        @RequestParam(name = "checkin")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        LocalDate checkin,
        @RequestParam(name = "checkout")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        LocalDate checkout) {
        ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> reservationResponse = new ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse>();
    return (reservationResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any list. The second one is definitely wrong because that would become a `ResponseEntity` holding no response (i.e. it is empty). The first one is suspicious too, since you have created a new response object which probably has nothing.

Comment: Yes. i dont created any list here. i want to know whether returning ways are ok or not. adding list should be their for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your **ReservationResponse** contains a list like this:

```
class ReservationResponse{
List<Rooms> availableRooms;
}
```

If like this then you can just return **ReservationResponse**  no need to add anything.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ReservationResponse getAvailableRooms(
        @RequestParam(name = "checkin")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        LocalDate checkin,
        @RequestParam(name = "checkout")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        LocalDate checkout) {
        ReservationResponse> reservationResponse = new ReservationResponse();
        List<Rooms> rooms = yourService.getAvailableRooms(checkIn,checkOut);
        reservationResponse.setAvailableRooms(rooms);
    return reservationResponse;
    }
```

or you can simply return rooms like this

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<Rooms> getAvailableRooms(
        @RequestParam(name = "checkin")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        LocalDate checkin,
        @RequestParam(name = "checkout")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        LocalDate checkout) {

        List<Rooms> rooms = yourService.getAvailableRooms(checkIn,checkOut);

    return rooms;
    }
```

Comment: Actually ReservationResponse is a entity which contain private set of fields and getters and setters.

Comment: So you can use first one by adjusting with your service data.

Comment: Yes here yourService not defined